# Failed when converting UIImage to base64 string

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, uiimage, base64

I'm trying to send image to server via JSON string. Problem is the server didn't see my image in PNG or JPG format. Here is code how i do it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aom50.png)

That how i convert parameters to JSON string
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC5hx.png)

What i want  - it's encode UIImage to base64 string and send to server.
Thank You!

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code to your question as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thats it. I just covering image to base64 and getting error for server - "Invalid file type. Type must be one of the following: jpg, gif, png"

Answer (score 0):

try using the below code and check if any error occurs or image value is nil

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
  if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {  
     let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0)) 
     let dict: [String: Any] = ["data": base64String] 
     do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
        if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
           socket.write(string)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Got same error form server - "Invalid file type. Type must be one of the following: jpg, gif, png"